# How to redeploy my laravel application to heroku when I deleted the url that heroku gave me

Tags: laravel, heroku

I have deleted that  in dashboard due to some errors during deployment with

> $  git push heroku master

and now I want to deploy my laravel application once again. But everytime during deployment it keeps on pushing to that old url. And not to the one that heroku gave me during when I type

> $ heroku create

What seems to be my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove old remote

```
git remote rm heroku
```

and add again with

```
heroku git:remote -a your-app-name
```

or

```
git remote set-url heroku <new-url>
```

Comment: And after this I can git push heroku master again?

Comment: I get something like this :  !    

ETIMEDOUT: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.205.34.111:443